# Porque o caminho da tradução não está sendo achado?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, i18n

Supondo que meu arquivo yml esta organizado dessa maneira:

```
pt-BR:
  alert_system:
    schedules:
      teste: 'ss'
      every: 'Todo Dia:'
      each: 'A Cada:'
      each_day: 'A Cada #{dias} Dias'
      on: 'Na data:'
```

Ao chamar de dentro de um decorator o comando:

```
I18n.t("alert_system.schedules.#{type.to_s.underscore} ")
```

Recebo como resposta a exceção Translate missing, sabendo que o comando "type.to_s.underscore" pode retornar "every", "on" e "each".
Porém ao executar no rails console os seguintes comandos

```
I18n.t("alert_system.schedules.on")
I18n.t("alert_system.schedules.every")
I18n.t("alert_system.schedules.each")
```

Apenas o primeiro apresenta a exceção Translate Missing.

Mesmo dentro do decorator o caminho estar correto, porque é apresentado a exceção?, não é possível concatenar variáveis?, e no console, porque apenas o finalizado em "on" apresenta erro?, seria uma palavra especial?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Poderia inserir o código do decorator? Pode ser algum problema com a variável "type".

Com relação ao translation missing de

```
I18n.t("alert_system.schedules.on")
```

Percebi que funciona se alterar o "on" para "on_date"

DE:

```
pt-BR:
  alert_system:
    schedules:
      teste: 'ss'
      every: 'Todo Dia:'
      each: 'A Cada:'
      each_day: 'A Cada #{dias} Dias'
      on: 'Na data:'
```

PARA:

```
pt-BR:
  alert_system:
    schedules:
      teste: 'ss'
      every: 'Todo Dia:'
      each: 'A Cada:'
      each_day: 'A Cada #{dias} Dias'
      on_date: 'Na data:'
```

Usando:

```
I18n.t("alert_system.schedules.on_date")
```

Isto ocorre porque o YAML altera automaticamente os parametros `on` e `off` para `true` e `false` respectivamente.
Se você jogar se guinte código dentro de um arquivo YAML chamado `x.yaml`:

```
pt-BR:
  alert_system:
    schedules:
      teste: 'ss'
      every: 'Todo Dia:'
      each: 'A Cada:'
      each_day: 'A Cada #{dias} Dias'
      on: 'Na data:'
```

E na sequência carregá-lo diretamente usando o YAML verá que o retorno será `true=>"Na data:"`:

```
>> YAML.load_file('x.yml')
=> {"pt-BR"=>{"alert_system"=>{"schedules"=>{"teste"=>"ss", "every"=>"Todo Dia:", "each"=>"A Cada:", "each_day"=>"A Cada \#{dias} Dias", true=>"Na data:"}}}}
```

Maiores informações no repositório da gem i18n no GitHub:

https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/issues/308

Espero que ajude!